# Prove that $x^n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[0,b]$ with $0 < b < 1$, but not uniformly on $[0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have been working on this for a bit now and I am not sure what to do. Here is the question (also in the title), and then the work I have so far.

**Question**

Prove that $x^n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[0,b]$ with $0 < b < 1$, but not uniformly on $[0,1)$

**My attempt**

Proof
Let $\epsilon>0.$ To show $f_n(x)=x^n \rightarrow0$ uniformly on $[0,b]$ with $0 \lt b \lt 1$, we need to show $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists N\in \Bbb N$ s.t.

$\vert f_n(x)-f(x) \vert \lt \epsilon$ when $n\geq N$ and $x\in [0,b]$.

Note that:

$\vert f_n(x)-f(x) \vert = \vert x^n-0 \vert = \vert x^n \vert \leq \vert b^n \vert $ (since $x\in[0,b])$.

I have also found that in order for $b^n \lt \epsilon$, we have that

$b^n \lt \epsilon \implies n \ln b \lt \ln \epsilon \implies n \lt \frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln b}$

but that is it. I am also not sure how to prove that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Thank you!

Comment: I did, and I just edited it. Thank you!

Comment: $b<1$ so $\ln{b}<0$ and therefore your inequality for $n$ should be the other way around. This means you can take $N=\frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln b}$ to finish the proof for the first part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that convergence is not uniform on $[0,1)$, note that

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)}|f_n(x) - 0| \geqslant f_n(1 - 1/n) = (1- 1/n)^n \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow e^{-1} \neq   0$$

Comment: ... and $\sup_{x \in [0,1)} |f_n(x) -0| \geqslant f_n(1- 1/n)$

Comment: So my understanding is since $b<1$, $f_n(1- 1/n) \implies f_n(1-1/b) = (1-1/b)^n $ which converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But I am not sure really what to make of your comment?

Comment: @DylanSkinner: See edits.  I'm trying to help you with your question about uniform convergence on $[0,1)$.

Comment: In order for $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly for $x \in [0,1)$ we must have $\sup_{x \in [0,1)}|f_n(x) - f(x) | \to 0$.  This fails if we can find any sequence $x_n \in [0,1)$ such that $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| \not\to 0$.

Comment: Convergence is clearly uniform on $[0,b]$ for all $0 < b < 1$.

Comment: @RLL So because $[0,b]$ is a compact set, uniform convergence is implied by Dini's Theorem, right? That is why convergence is clearly uniform on $[0,b]$?

Comment: @DylanSkinner:  It converges uniformly on $[0,b]$ for a much simpler reason.  We have $|f_n(x) - 0| \leqslant b^n$ for all $0 \leqslant x \leqslant b$.  Since $b < 1$ we have $b^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N(\epsilon)$ independent of $x$ such that $|f_n(x) - 0| \leqslant b^n < \epsilon$ for all $n > N(\epsilon)$ and ALL $x \in [0,b]$.

Comment: Dini's theorem works as well.  Here $f_n \geqslant f_{n+1}$, $f_n$ is continuous and the limit function (identically zero) is continuous.